# File read/write in Android on runtime

Tags: android, file, gradle

I am developing **[this](https://github.com/iccaka/IntervalTimer)** Android app. I want to be able to write information (number of sets, work interval length and rest interval length) to a file during runtime when the user presses the 'START' button, so the next time he enters, everything is saved. I tried putting a file called 'parameters' inside the 'main/assets' folder, but I soon realized, that this folder is read-only. I then tried putting the file inside the 'res/raw' folder, but I can't change the file during runtime.

***How can I read and write information during runtime and where should I put the file?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the app it seems the data that it needs to store is key-value pair and for such data - you should use the `SharedPreferences` APIs.

The `SharedPrefernce` also points to a file containing key-value pairs and provides simple methods to read and write them. The **advantage** of using `SharedPreferences` can be that each `SharedPreferences` file is managed by the framework and you can control if the file can be private or shared.

You can create a new shared preference file or access an existing one by calling `getSharedPreferences()` You Use this if you need multiple shared preference files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter. You can call this from any Context in your app.

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences(
getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

This code accesses the shared preferences file that's identified by the resource string R.string.preference_file_key and opens it using the **private** mode so the file is accessible by only your app

To write to a shared preferences file, create a `SharedPreferences.Editor` by calling edit() on your SharedPreferences.

For example,

```
with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putInt(getString(R.string.your_data_key), newData)
    commit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your case doesn't go well with files

don't do it with files. 
do it with shared-preferences or sqlite databases (or any other objectbox, realm etc).